# Como faço em XSLT para pegar os atributos dentro de nome, da minha tag item, somente se for verdadeira?

Tags: xml, path, xslt

```
<bloco>

   <item nome="imagem">true</item>
    <item nome="imagem">false</item>

</bloco>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use um template para selecionar todos os elementos `item`, teste o valor do conteúdo (usando `.` ou `node()` ou `text()`) e imprima o valor do atributo `nome` se o conteúdo for igual à string `'true'`.

Eis um exemplo de folha de estilo:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:if test=". = 'true'">
            <xsl:value-of select="@nome" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```